# Bathtub valve that changes flow to shower head leaks

Tags: plumbing

My bathtub has a pull up valve that’s supposed to channel the water from the bathtub faucet to the shower head but it leaks a lot of water out of the tub faucet when the shower is on. What’s wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: A picture would help a great deal here. All you've done is describe a generic setup.

Answer (score 2):

I take it from your description that the diverter is in the tub spout and so it leaks out the spout into the tub. The leak is not going into the wall, right? This type of diverter does leak much more than the diverter inside the wall, but the leak is of no real consequence.

But if the leak is really excessive or it bothers you, then AFIK the only solution is replacement of the spout. AFIK there is no replaceable seal inside Sometimes it's metal-on-metal in the spout and the sealing surfaces wear with use.

See [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yq6FYfqKO0g).

Comment: +1 exactly right (except that they are not all "metal-to-metal" anymore, some incorporate a rubber gasket; but still no replacing parts. You have to swap the spout).

Comment: I discovered my spout leaked in the wall because of a lack of teflon tape. IMHO you can’t use too much tape.